# Is it possible to change the interface of a MsgBox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, popup, msgbox

Im trying to make an instruction msgbox and i want to make it look nice i want it to look like a Dialog Cloud. Should i use a msgbox or other tools ? any suggestions and answers would be awesome !

Comment: Make your own form and viola!

Comment: Sorry for this kind of question.. i cant show an image.. 
i cant describe a proper way to elaborate my idea sorry again for the disturbance @OneFineDay

Comment: Not a disturbance, if the framework does not provide something - you build it.

Comment: Making your own message box as @OneFineDay stated is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the successor of conventional message boxes : **TaskDialog**

Here is a showcase of what customization is possible with them:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760441(v=vs.85).aspx

It is accessible through .NET using the **Windows Api Code Pack**:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/

If it is not sufficient then as others said, code your own message box :D